# R : quantmod's chartSeries addRSI show different answer than TTR's RSI

Tags: r, quantmod

Difference seen between quantmod package’s chartSeries()+addRSI() and TTR’s RSI()

chartSeries shows RSI at 54.50
and TTR shows it at 73.49

Any reason why the difference ?

Thanks 
GW

```
todate = Sys.Date()
fromdate = '2015-01-01'
tick = "STZ"
getSymbols(tick, src = 'yahoo', from = fromdate, to = todate)
chartSeries(STZ ,name = tick, theme="white",  TA="addRSI()")
price <- Cl(STZ)
rsi <- RSI(price,  2)
tail(rsi)

                 EMA
2016-09-23 88.804068
2016-09-26 40.403057
2016-09-27 57.262952
2016-09-28 28.881392
2016-09-29  8.375952
2016-09-30 73.493351
```

Answer (score 1):

`rsi <- RSI(price,  2)` is using `n=2`, whereas `addRSI` is using the default `n=14` since you did not pass in the value of `n` in `addRSI`.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks, with 14 put in rsi <- RSI(price,  14), it has the same result

Comment: @Gardn Water *What should I do when someone answers my question?* http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers